# Check if entry of one table is in another one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables.

First is filled with languagecodes (e.g. en, de, fr,..).

Second looks like:

```
 ID  | Lang | Text
----------------
..1..|..en..|..one..
..1..|..de..|..eins..
..1..|..fr..|..une..
..2..|..en..|..two..
..2..|..de..|..zwei..
```

Now what I want is to go trough the seconde table over every ID, check if there is a row for every language and if not add a empty row. So for the example above the second table will have an additional row:

```
..2..|..fr..|.. ..
```

Is there any way to realize this in SQL Server?

Comment: This is basic join question, please read some SQL manual on joins.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: the additional row in the 3rd column text should get what value?

Comment: @sagi Just an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This whould be basic join question if you have ID at first table so the code is:

```
declare @tabLanguages table (id int,Lang char(2))

    insert into @tabLanguages 
    values (1,'en'),(2,'de'),(3,'fr')


    declare @Translation table (id int, Lang char(2), Text nvarchar(200))

    insert into @Translation
    values
    (1,'en','one'),
    (1,'de','eins'),
    (1,'fr','.une'),     
    (2,'en','two'),
    (2,'de','zwei')


    select isnull(t.id,l.Id) as ID,
            isnull(t.Lang,l.Lang) as Lang,
            t.Text
    from @tabLanguages l
    left outer join @Translation t on l.id = t.Id
    order by Id
```

But if you don't have Id in the first table then you can use following:

```
    declare @tabLanguages table (Lang char(2))

    insert into @tabLanguages 
    values ('en'),('de'),('fr')


    declare @Translation table (id int, Lang char(2), Text nvarchar(200))

    insert into @Translation
    values
    (1,'en','one'),
    (1,'de','eins'),
    (1,'fr','.une'),     
    (2,'en','two'),
    (2,'de','zwei')



    select  isnull(t.id,l.Id) as ID,
            isnull(t.Lang,l.Lang) as Lang,
            t.Text
    from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by Lang) as Id
    from @tabLanguages t
    ) l
    left outer join @Translation t on l.id = t.Id
    order by l.Id
```